# Can you change the backgroung color for select column headers for a List in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list

I am wondering if it is possible to change the background color of select column header for a list without using SharePoint Designer.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could CSS and/or javascript/JQuery to select the header elements and set the background color property. If you are in 2013, you could also use JSLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a script editor webpart to the same page where your list is and set the color for the selected column header using this CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-headerCellStyleMenuOpen {
     background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
</style>
```

**Edit:** Just saw that this was for 2010. As i don't have access to a 2010 farm anymore, this might or might now work. Use F12 developer tools to find the right element to style.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, picked up CSS yesterday. But how to select the column header that I want to make a modification to. So for example if I only want to change the background for "FirstName" and "LastName" how do I select those